# Track page when fragment is shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to implement app analytics, so that every "page" (fragment) is tracked when it is shown. The navigation between fragments consists of adding, replacing and attaching (legacy code) fragments in fragment transactions. To have control over the back button, I've made these navigation fragment transactions added to the backstack. The pages need to be tracked every time they become visible to the user, wether this is the first time the fragment is shown, navigated from another fragment or navigated back by popping the backstack.

**1:** What would be a good strategy to do this? Manually tracking the page at every fragment transaction seems too cumbersome.

The fragment's lifecycle hook methods are not consistently called because of the various fragment transactions. I know that there is the FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.

**2:** How to use this OnBackStackChangeldListener for my use case correctly? Manually keep track of the previous and current page would work for hierarchical navigation (with backstack), but not when navigating to same level fragments..

Answer (score 0):

To track the fragment visibility state, you can use [setUserVisibleHint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)).
Try the following..

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible){
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible){
        //fragment is visible
    }else {
        //   fragment is not visible
    }
}
```